# Design pattern for if-else with common logic within the conditionals

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have to implement a solution where the code behaves differently according to a different condition.

For example:

```java
if(condition) {
   //create one object
} else {
   //create another object
}
oneCommonMethod();
if(condition) {
   //do one thing
} else {
   //do another thing
}
anotherCommonMethod();
```

Even the code inside the conditions is shared sometimes, it's just slightly variations of it. What would be the best approach here? What would be the best Design Pattern?

Comment: This sounds like a lack of polymorphism rather than a lack of a design pattern. The code being handled in the `if/else` blocks sounds like it's a similar responsibility, but handled by two different objects. Those two objects should have a shared method/interface with `#doThing1` and `#doThing2`. You would then instantiate the appropriate subtype of the interface, and call those methods directly, turning the example into 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to have one "if-else" statement – whenever you can achieve the same goal with just one, there's no need to do an extra one and negatively affect performance.

In your code, given that the 'condition' is shared amongst both "if" statements (1), and given that the two "if" statements are at the same place in the program (2), it is better to merge the two "if" statments like this:

```
if(condition) {
   //create one object
   oneCommonMethod();
   //do one thing
   anotherCommonMethod();
} else {
   //create another object
   oneCommonMethod();
   //do another thing
   anotherCommonMethod();
}
```

This code achieves exactly the same goal as yours, except it's more effecient with just one "if" statement.

Comment: The problem is that the "do one thing" bit should happen before the someCommonMethod(). Sorry, I've edited the code

Comment: In my answer, the "do one thing" happens before the "someCommonMethod()". I've edited the answer to reflect your change.

Comment: I've edited the original code to make it a bit clearer. I need the first if-else to happen before the first common method and the second if-else to happen before the second common method.

Comment: My code should do exactly what you intend: When condition is true -> do the 4 tasks. When it is false -> do the other 4 tasks. Notice that the two common method calls are shared, but that's okay, since this is the simplist way to exactly achieve what you've requested.

Comment: @AhmadMtera, your code calls the exact same methods in both, the then and else branch, so it can be reduced to `oneCommonMethod(); anotherCommonMethod();` Apart from that, a simple if-else is not enough because the result of the condition can change due to the call of `oneCommonMethod()` in between the two if statements.

Comment: @Mihe The original poster did not indicate that oneCommonMethod() may affect the condition. Without any more info, his code can only be reduced to one 'if' statement. I don't see any more simplifications with the given details, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [Strategy Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) for the do something aspect. For the create an object aspect you could see if any of the creational patterns such factory or factoryMethod suits your usecase.

Different strategies can call into shared methods when required